# Image uploaded to cloudinary twice

Tags: node.js, image, express, multer, cloudinary

I try to uplaod Image to cloudinary but when I upload one image it uploaded twice to cloudinary and when I uplaod 2 it uploaded 4 etc and returned uploadedFiles =[ ]. so whats wrong with my code

I use multer-cloudinary package and multer as a middleware
..........................................................................

```
app.post("/multiple-upload", multerMiddleware.array("files"), async (req, res) => {
try {
if (!req.files) {
return res.status(200).json({ message: "Invalid file type" });
}
let uploadedFiles = imageUploaderHandler({ files: req.files });
return res.status(200).json({ message: "File stored", uploadedFiles });
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
return res
.status(500)
.json({ message: "Something went wrong while uplaoding this item" });
}
})

const imageUploaderHandler = async ({ files }) => {
let file = {};
let uploadedFiles = [];
let newImages = files.map(async (item) => {
let result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(item.path)
console.log(result);
file.cloudinaryPublicId = result.public_id;
file.fileUrl = result.secure_url;
file.fileName = result.original_filename;
uploadedFiles.push(file);

});
return await Promise.all(newImages);
};


//Multer-cloudinary config

import cloudinary from "cloudinary";
import { CloudinaryStorage } from "multer-storage-cloudinary";

cloudinary.v2.config({
  cloud_name: CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: API_KEY,
  api_secret: API_SECRET,
});
let cloudinaryVersion = cloudinary.v2;

const fileStorage = new CloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary: cloudinaryVersion,
  folder: "uploads",
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const date = format(new Date(), "dd-MM-yy");
    const fileType = file.mimetype == "video/mp4" ? "VIDEO" : "IMAGE";
    const fileNameFormat = `${date}-${fileType}-${file.originalname}`;
    cb(null, fileNameFormat);
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|mp4)$/i)) {
    cb(null, false);
  } else {
    cb(null, true);
  }
};
export const multerMiddleware = multer({
  storage: fileStorage,
  fileFilter,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your coding method isn't clean, it has many mistakes, you can use with `q` and `async` module solve your issue like this :

```
let async = require('async');
let q = require('q');
const imageUploaderHandler = async ({ files }) => {
  let defer = q.defer(); // define a defer
  let file = {};
  let uploadedFiles = [];
  async.eachSeries(files, async (item)=>{ //it is a loop 
   try {
    let result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(item.path)
    console.log(result);
    file.cloudinaryPublicId = result.public_id;
    file.fileUrl = result.secure_url;
    file.fileName = result.original_filename;
    uploadedFiles.push(file);
   } catch (error) {
     console.log("something is wrong : ", error)
   } 
  },()=>{
    defer.resolve(uploadedFiles) //its callback when finished loop,do something, we want return result as a promise
  })
  return defer.promise; // this function returns promise
  };
```

because `q` is used this function return `promise` as do like this in route:

```
let uploadedFiles = await imageUploaderHandler({ files: req.files });//use await
```

check the [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) documentation and [q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) documentation

Comment: if your problem is not solved, leave a comment

Comment: add multerMiddleware to the question

Comment: I added multer middleware to the question

Comment: show me console.log(req.files) at the first of app.post("/multiple-upload")

Comment: [
  {
    fieldname: 'files',
    originalname: 'download (1).jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    path: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwfxxq7k/image/upload/v1610972721/uploads/ojucgefzjpjdhnepmg2s.jpg',
    size: 5189,
    filename: 'uploads/ojucgefzjpjdhnepmg2s'
  },
  {
    fieldname: 'files',
    originalname: 'download.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    path: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwfxxq7k/image/upload/v1610972721/uploads/vi612hnz67e5mdjkjqwd.jpg',
    size: 3784,
    filename: 'uploads/vi612hnz67e5mdjkjqwd'
  }
]